# check that the dimensions of item are greater than given values

Tags: sql, comparison, dimensions

I'm trying to write a SQL query, where the data with all items and their dimensions will be pulled and a following condition must be satisfied: length >=20 OR width >=14 OR height >=10 (all items that wouldn't fit into a 20x14x10 container). The problem is that the height might be greater than length (imagine flipping the item in space). I wrote a code, but I don't think it would catch all cases. Below is the code I tried:

```
select 
items.bin_id,
items.bin_type_name,    
items.bin_usage_name,    
items.isbn,
items.boo,
items.quantity,
ma.pkg_height,
ma.pkg_width,  
ma.pkg_length,    
ma.pkg_weight,
items.owner
from items 
left join BOOKER.D_MP_PHYSICAL_ITEMS ma
on items.boo = ma.asin

where ((ma.pkg_length >= 20 AND ma.pkg_width >= 14 AND ma.pkg_height >= 10) OR 
    (ma.pkg_length >= 14 AND ma.pkg_width >= 10 AND ma.pkg_height >= 20) OR 
    (ma.pkg_length >= 10 AND ma.pkg_width >= 20 AND ma.pkg_height >= 14) OR

    ((ma.pkg_length >= 20 AND ma.pkg_width >= 10 AND ma.pkg_height >= 14) OR 
    (ma.pkg_length >= 14 AND ma.pkg_width >= 20 AND ma.pkg_height >= 10) OR     
    (ma.pkg_length >= 10 AND ma.pkg_width >= 14 AND ma.pkg_height >= 20))
```

Another idea I had was to select the maximum value from the item's dimensions and check if it's greater than 20, then select the minimum value and see if it's greater than 10 and check if the last number is greater than 14 (in case where two first values give FALSE), but I can't put it in SQL

Answer (score 0):

I guess the below logic will work (Basically I have tried writing a query for logic you have mentioned in the later part of your question):

```
with temp_cte as (
    select 
    items.*, ma.*,
    Select dim from
      (SELECT dim, row_number() over (order by dim desc) as rn
       FROM (VALUES (ma.pkg_length), (ma.pkg_height), (ma.pkg_width)) AS value(dim)) where rn = 1) as length,
    Select dim from
      (SELECT dim, row_number() over (order by dim desc) as rn
       FROM (VALUES (ma.pkg_length), (ma.pkg_height), (ma.pkg_width)) AS value(dim)) where rn = 2) as height,
    Select dim from
      (SELECT dim, row_number() over (order by dim desc) as rn
       FROM (VALUES (ma.pkg_length), (ma.pkg_height), (ma.pkg_width)) AS value(dim)) where rn = 3) as width
    from items 
    left join BOOKER.D_MP_PHYSICAL_ITEMS ma
    on items.boo = ma.asin
    where 
        length >= 20 or height >= 14 or width >= 10
)

Select 
    bin_id,
    bin_type_name,    
    bin_usage_name,    
    isbn,
    boo,
    quantity,
    pkg_height,
    pkg_width,  
    pkg_length,    
    pkg_weight,
    owner
from temp_cte;
```